# Override shouldcomponentupdate with HOC

Tags: reactjs

May I know is it possible to change the behaviour (override) the child component of shouldcomponentupdate with HOC instead of extend? Any example on this?

Comment: In the HOC docs? https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/higher-order-components.html Which states that it's bad, mmkay?

Comment: Can you expand on why you want to do this? As the other commenter pointed out it's a bad idea to mutate the wrapped component, but if you want a more restrictive `shouldComponentUpdate` for the wrapped component then defining it in the HOC would work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. It's possible up to a certain extent.

We can implement the `shouldComponentUpdate` of the HoC, and it will have the same effect of overriding the `shouldComponentUpdate` of Child component as usually in React Child component only rerender if the parent rerender.

```js
function HoC(WrappedComponent) {
  return class extends React.Component {

    shouldComponentUpdate() {
      // change the behaviour here
    }

    render() {
      return <WrappedComponent {...this.props} />;
    }
  };
}
```

However, this will not work if the Child component has any **internal state changes** with `setState` or it is [forced to rerender](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-component.html#forceupdate) from a different source other than the updates from the parent. As an example, if the Child component is connected to a Redux store with `connect`, it will rerender when it gets updates from the store regardless of overridden `shouldComponentUpdate` behavior in the HoC.

Comment: if the child also has shouldComponentUpdate(..) , after the HOC.shouldComponentUpdate is excuted, the child.shouldComponentUpdate(..) still get executed. I want to prevent the child from executing it

Comment: It will not execute Child.scu if you return false in HoC.scu. In this approach, it's the only way to prevent executing Child.scu.

Comment: Let say Hoc.scu return true, then it will execute the child.scu to find out whether it need to be render the child ? I want to skip the checking of child.scu because the child.scu has condition always return false, i want the HOC force the child to always render

Comment: I can't think of any way to achieve what you need with this approach. It seems you don't have any control over the Child component. Is that 3rd party control or something like that? If you can give more context, I might be able to help you to find a workaround.

Comment: yes, u a right, i do not want to modify the child.scu as we are working in a team, i do not want to modify another person code for my use case.